# cordova failed to download plugin cordova-custom-config

Tags: ionic-framework, plugins

I've been trying exhaustingly to build my ionic app for both ios and android. I've added and removed platforms multiple times. Upgraded and downgraded my ionic app and java JDK but nothing works. Right now the common error seems to be with the plugin 'cordova-custom-config'.

When trying to add the **ios** platform through the command `$ sudo ionic cordova platform add ios@latest --fetch --save --verbose` the error is:

```
Discovered plugin "cordova-custom-config" in config.xml. Adding it to the project

Failed to restore plugin "cordova-custom-config" from config.xml. You might need to try adding it again. Error: Failed to fetch plugin cordova-custom-config@^5.0.1 via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! Command failed: /usr/local/bin/git clone -q git://github.com/xiangpingmeng/plist.js.git /Users/adamgoldberg/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-87b2ddaf
npm ERR! /Users/adamgoldberg/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-87b2ddaf/.git: Permission denied
npm ERR!

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/adamgoldberg/.npm/_logs/2018-02-07T04_04_30_105Z-debug.log

--save flag or autosave detected

Saving ios@latest into config.xml file ...
[ERROR] Exception:
```

When trying to add **android** platform through the command `$ sudo ionic cordova platform add android@6.3.0 --fetch --save --verbose the error` is the same as for **ios**. Please note that i'm adding **android@6.3.0** and not **android@latest** because latest (7.0.0) is buggy.

When I try to add the **cordova-custom-config** plugin by itself through the command `$ sudo cordova plugin add cordova-custom-config --fetch --verbose` the error is:

```
(node:16626) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): CordovaError: Failed to fetch plugin cordova-custom-config@^5.0.1 via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! Command failed: /usr/local/bin/git clone -q git://github.com/xiangpingmeng/plist.js.git /Users/adamgoldberg/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-0ad7ea7b
npm ERR! /Users/adamgoldberg/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-0ad7ea7b/.git: Permission denied
npm ERR!

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/adamgoldberg/.npm/_logs/2018-02-07T04_12_20_482Z-debug.log
(node:16626) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Here is my `ionic info`

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
    Cordova Platforms  : none
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    ios-sim           : 6.0.0
    Node              : v8.8.1
    npm               : 5.6.0
    OS                : macOS High Sierra
    Xcode             : Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : /Users/adamgoldberg/Library/Android/sdk

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a problem when attempting to install into a project which previously contained an old version of the plugin.
Try cleaning out previous remnants:

```
rm -Rf node_modules/cordova-custom-config and rm -Rf plugins/cordova-custom-config
```

If still having issues, install with [new cordova-fetch option](https://cordova.apache.org/news/2016/05/24/tools-release.html)

```
cordova plugin add cordova-custom-config --fetch
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to plugin directory :

   `cd plugins/cordova-custom-config/`
2. Install manually

   `npm install`